# Post with jquery and return/redirect different view with model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

i have a form which is posted using jquery,

i could use regular form submission i suppose.. but is there some way to have my result push a new view and model based on the post results? Someone suggested what i want to do is redirect.

my controller returns:

```
return View("User/Default", model);
```

but because i am posting with AJAX this is not working. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By calling `View()` You're returning an entire document (ViewResult), which can be used by your ajax `success` callback, but maybe you're looking for [PartialViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult.aspx), which would be an html fragment and faster/easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Specifically i want to go to a different view than the one being posted from. I don't want to handle the response in the original view.. I'd like to just redirect. Again.. probably doesn't make sense to post using Ajax in this case.. But maybe people are doing this?

Comment: What about redirecting to another action where i pass the model to the other action? Will this actually cause a redirect in the browser?

Comment: @billyjean: Add the redirect comment to your question by editing it.  That will change the answers you get signficantly, and is actually an easy problem to solve.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+redirect

Comment: OK thanks.. will do. What is the solution? I checked a few questions from the list you posted and was unable to determine the answer..

Answer (score 0):

BC's answer probably fits your needs. If you're seeking true awesomeness ;) you could let your controller return a json result and use [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) to render the views clientside.

Comment: Yeah no doubt.. But i am using knockoutjs and doing some complicated validation. With knockout it's super easy to post your js model with JSON. And i essentially need to go to another view entirely once i post. Maybe i should just replace part of the DOM.. but overall it will make more sense to go to a new "page".